# VBA Excel form content is missing

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I have an Excel 2007 template that presents a form to the user to make various selections, and then generates a report based on the selections.  It has been working fine for several years.  Now, when you open the template on Computer A, the user form is missing all of the selection criteria content.  It opens correctly on Computer B.  Both are running Windows 10, the exact same version of Excel, both have macros enabled, and the Trust settings are the same. I have "repaired" Office 2007 on A.

If I go into the Developer menu on Computer A and open the Form itself (as if for editing), it is empty, but on Computer B it's fine.

Here is a screen shot from A:
[image: Form in VBA]

And from B:
[image: Form in VBA]

Both of these were launched from the the exact same file that resides on on a NAS.  The same thing happens if I copy the file to the desktop of each computer and open it locally.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  I am at wit's end...

Comment: Can you make sure computer A has all Windows and Office updates. Then, on each PC, from visual basic, can you click Tools>References and compare what references are being used and see if any are "MISSING".

Comment: Maybe your workbook is corrupt on computer A. Delete the UserForm from the Computer A. Export the UserForm from computer B and import it on Computer A and see if that works fine then.

Comment: David, References are identical on both computers, and the same ones are selected on both.

Comment: sktneer, I copied the file from the NAS and pasted it to the desktop on each computer.  B works, A doesn't.

Comment: Thanks to David and sktneer for responding, but there must be something different on A that is preventing the same exact file to open properly. I just don't know where to look...

Comment: are you able to create a simple form with just a couple controls, and does it display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the background color of the frame objects is transparent on B and solid on A
it is quite possible that the controls are not children of the frame object, but actually are the children of the main window, and the frame covers them

move the frame object in the editor and see if the controls are behind it

it may have something to do with theme setting on the computer

Comment: jsotola - here is a screen shot from A showing that the subframes are all in the main frame, but their content is missing.  The themes on both computers are the same.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y7z0lpib307533/Screenshot%202017-07-23%2009.31.40.png?dl=0

Comment: did you move one of the subframes and looked "behind" it ?

Comment: jsotola - yes, I moved a couple of subframes - nothing "behind" them.  I'll try to create a new form this evening and let you know.

Comment: OK, I opened a new Excel file, created a form with a couple of control buttons, and saved it as an xlt.  I then quit Excel and opened the saved template, and the form is still there. So if the form is created on A, it's OK on A.  I suppose I could recreate the original form on A, but it has a ton of controls, selections, drop downs, etc., all connected to a lot of code.  It would take a very long time to do it.  I'm going to try uninstalling Office completely and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: OK, reinstalling Excel didn't work, but I solved the problem in a roundabout way.  I have a habit of keeping old versions of these templates in an archive folder, in case the client wants to go back to a previous version.  I tried the previous version (v258) of this template on A, and it worked!  Since there were only two small modifications from v258 to the latest one (v259), I simply added them to v258, and replaced the non-working v259 with the modified v258 (renamed to v259).  It works!  Still no idea what was wrong, but it appears resolved.  Thanks for all the support!